# [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown following UINavigationController push

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

This is an observation more than anything, because I appear to have found a work-around...

The code below fails to work *when it's in a controller which has been pushed onto a UINavigationController stack*. In this situation `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` consistently returns `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`.

```
-(void)layoutAccordingToOrientation {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    NSLog(@"layoutAccordingToOrientation/orientation==%i", orientation);
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        :
        _detailToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 660, 1024, 44);
    } else {
        :
        _detailToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 916, 768, 44);
    }
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self layoutAccordingToOrientation];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

The following call *has* been made:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

To work around this `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`-problem, I now use the following instead:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    etc.
} else {
    etc.
}
```

... which works every time.

Still, I fail to see why the first variation would not work in the context of a pushed view controller. Ideas anyone? Is it simply a bug?

Comment: I am having the same problem, however I am not able to get your work around to work in my situation either.

Answer (score 4):

I could think of a couple of things here, but I'm not sure they're what you're looking for...

First, when the app is launched, usually the device orientation returns `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` for performance reasons. One thing you could try is to layout your subviews inside a .nib or in your Storyboard, with the correct autoresizing options, and let iOS do its thing.

Secondly, if you're like me, maybe you're testing on a device that's right beside your computer, laying on a table. Well, in that case, you are **not** going to get the `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` thing. You should actually test for `UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])`. If the device is laying down on its back, for example, it returns yes to that statement. This also means that when you use `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)`, you're getting the right result for the wrong reason. The `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape` is returning false not because the device's orientation is `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`, but because it's invalid.

Not so sure if this helped, but it took me a while to figure that out and I thought it would be nice to share this info! :)